# Template error: instance of function references undefined resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

**Background**

I am trying to add service role for codebuild via cloud formation. 
I keep getting the following error but I am not sure how to fix it.

> Failed to create the changeset: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed:
>   Waiter encountered a terminal failure state Status: FAILED. Reason:
>   Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource
>   CodeBuildServiceRole

I have the following file that has my codebuild configuration

```
Mappings:
  'Fn::Transform':
    Name: 'AWS::Include'
    Parameters:
      Location: s3://source-code-for-download-by-ec2s/include.yaml

Parameters:
  RepositoryBranch:
    Type: String
    Description: git branch to test and deploy
  OAuthToken:
    Type: String
    Description: >
      OAuth Token for this code pipeline to connect to GitHub to download the source code
      when the webhook publishes a push event
    NoEcho: true

Resources:
  CodeBuildProject:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub 'xxxxxxx-dev-branch-${XXXXXXXXX}-xxxx'
      Artifacts: 
        Type: S3
        Location: 'xxxxxxxxx'
        Path: !Sub 'XXXXXXXXXX/${XXXXXXXX}'
        Name: 'repo.zip'
        Packaging: ZIP
      BadgeEnabled: true
      Environment:
        ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
        Image: 'abcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxabcxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxabcxxxxxxxxxx'
        ImagePullCredentialsType: SERVICE_ROLE
        Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
        PrivilegedMode: true
      LogsConfig:
        CloudWatchLogs:
          Status: ENABLED
      ServiceRole: !GetAtt CodeBuildServiceRole.Arn
      Source:
        Type: GITHUB
        Auth:
          Type: OAUTH
          Resource: !Sub '${OAuthToken}'
        Location: 'https://github.com/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx.git'
        GitCloneDepth: 0  # no need to download git version history with the repo, just grab the latest version of this branch
        ReportBuildStatus: true
      SourceVersion: !Ref RepositoryBranch
      TimeoutInMinutes: 60
```

I also have additional file where I am creating the service role policy and also adding codebuild as action.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Resources:

  CodeBuildServiceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: AWSCodeBuildServiceRole-role-created-by-cloudformation
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument: '{
          "Version": "2012-10-17", 
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Action": "sts:AssumeRole", 
              "Effect": "Allow", 
              "Principal": {
                "Service": "codebuild.amazonaws.com"
              }
            }
          ]
        }'
      ManagedPolicyArns: [!Ref CodeBuildServiceRolePolicy]  
      Path: /service-role/

    CodeBuildServiceRolePolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyName: AWSCodeBuildServiceRole-policy-created-by-cloudformation
      Description: 'Policy meant for CodeBuild service role that CodeBuild runs-as to deploy code from Github to S3'

      PolicyDocument: '{
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Action": [
                        "iam:PassRole"
                    ],
                    "Resource": "*",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Condition": {
                        "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                            "iam:PassedToService": [
                                "cloudformation.amazonaws.com",
                                "elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com",
                                "ec2.amazonaws.com",
                                "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Action": [
                        "codebuild:*"
                    ],
                    "Resource": "*",
                    "Effect": "Allow"
                },
                {
                    "Action": [
                        "codedeploy:CreateDeployment",
                        "codedeploy:GetApplication",
                        "codedeploy:GetApplicationRevision",
                        "codedeploy:GetDeployment",
                        "codedeploy:GetDeploymentConfig",
                        "codedeploy:RegisterApplicationRevision"
                    ],
                    "Resource": "*",
                    "Effect": "Allow"
                },
                {
                    "Action": [
                        "elasticbeanstalk:*",
                        "ec2:*",
                        "elasticloadbalancing:*",
                        "autoscaling:*",
                        "cloudwatch:*",
                        "s3:*",
                        "sns:*",
                        "cloudformation:*",
                        "rds:*",
                        "sqs:*",
                        "ecs:*"
                    ],
                    "Resource": "*",
                    "Effect": "Allow"
                },
                {
                    "Action": [
                        "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                        "lambda:ListFunctions"
                    ],
                    "Resource": "*",
                    "Effect": "Allow"
                },
                {
                    "Action": [
                        "opsworks:CreateDeployment",
                        "opsworks:DescribeApps",
                        "opsworks:DescribeCommands",
                        "opsworks:DescribeDeployments",
                        "opsworks:DescribeInstances",
                        "opsworks:DescribeStacks",
                        "opsworks:UpdateApp",
                        "opsworks:UpdateStack"
                    ],
                    "Resource": "*",
                    "Effect": "Allow"
                },
                {
                    "Action": [
                        "cloudformation:CreateStack",
                        "cloudformation:DeleteStack",
                        "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                        "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
                        "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
                        "cloudformation:DeleteChangeSet",
                        "cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet",
                        "cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet",
                        "cloudformation:SetStackPolicy",
                        "cloudformation:ValidateTemplate"
                    ],
                    "Resource": "*",
                    "Effect": "Allow"
                },
                {
                    "Action": [
                        "codebuild:BatchGetBuilds",
                        "codebuild:StartBuild"
                    ],
                    "Resource": "*",
                    "Effect": "Allow"
                },
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": [
                        "devicefarm:ListProjects",
                        "devicefarm:ListDevicePools",
                        "devicefarm:GetRun",
                        "devicefarm:GetUpload",
                        "devicefarm:CreateUpload",
                        "devicefarm:ScheduleRun"
                    ],
                    "Resource": "*"
                },
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": [
                        "servicecatalog:ListProvisioningArtifacts",
                        "servicecatalog:CreateProvisioningArtifact",
                        "servicecatalog:DescribeProvisioningArtifact",
                        "servicecatalog:DeleteProvisioningArtifact",
                        "servicecatalog:UpdateProduct"
                    ],
                    "Resource": "*"
                },
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": [
                        "cloudformation:ValidateTemplate"
                    ],
                    "Resource": "*"
                },
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Action": [
                        "ecr:DescribeImages"
                    ],
                    "Resource": "*"
                }
            ],
            "Version": "2012-10-17"
        }'

Outputs:
  CodeBuildServiceRoleExportThingArn:
    Description: 'ARN of code-build service role, to be imported by CodeBuild stacks'
    Value: !GetAtt CodeBuildServiceRole.Arn
    Export:
      Name: CodeBuildServiceRoleArn
```

**Question**

Both the files are in the same directory so i am not sure why i am getting this error i would love some input as i have been stuck on this for some time.

Comment: have you fixed this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anywhere that you're nesting the stacks, so I assume these are two distinct stacks? In that case, you can't just reference the entities in another stack - they aren't aware of each other. But you can use CFN Intrinsic Functions to grab the stack outputs.

Keep in mind, the stack with `CodeBuildServiceRole` will have to be ran first. Also, I suggest you add something unique to the export (maybe stack name) so there aren't naming collisions.

Then this should work:

```
Resources:
  CodeBuildProject:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    Properties:
      ServiceRole: !ImportValue CodeBuildServiceRoleArn
```

Comment: Which stack gives you that error? The one exporting the value, or the one importing it?

Comment: my bad i was creating both stacks using same stack name and that was the cause now i am good